# UISplitViewController asks for photo permission when it rotates

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode6.1

I have a project with a UITabBarViewController and a UISplitViewController as its first tab. The master UITableViewController can display a thumbnail if there is one but it's supposed to be set up so that it won't ask permission on this screen. The third tab is a photos screen that does ask permission as expected and allows the user to establish thumbnails for the first tab.

The app will never ask for photo permission on first launch when displaying the split view regardless of whether it is portrait or landscape and if it is not rotated, the photo tab will ask permission as expected. However, if the initial split view is rotated, iOS will ask for photo permission during rotation.

I don't have any code dealing with rotation and all other rotation and navigation that I have found behaves as expected. I am using Swift, Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1 both in the simulator and on a device.

Answer (score 0):

When rotating, the app was calling viewDidLoad in the Photo tab. I moved the code that triggered the permission alert from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear and solved the problem.